# Why doesn't Rselium find a button if I already pass it the css selector in the findElement () function?

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rselenium

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKPc6.png)I am trying to make a function in R, with Rselenium, that downloads information from the following [página](https://listanominal.ine.mx/ESTADISTICAS/index.php) but when trying to click on a button with findElement () this button is not found, I tried to search with the css selectors like the first ones but for this one it did not work, the button is boton_edad. I attach my code.

I appreciate any help.

```
library(RSelenium)
library(xml2)
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

######
controlador<- rsDriver(browser = 'firefox')
controlador_remoto <- controlador[["client"]]
######
controlador_remoto$navigate('https://listanominal.ine.mx/ESTADISTICAS/index.php')
######
boton_estadisticas <- controlador_remoto$findElement(using = 'css selector',value = ".fa-bar-chart+ span")
boton_estadisticas$highlightElement()#li:nth-child(2) .dropdown-toggle
boton_estadisticas$clickElement()
######
boton_sexo <- controlador_remoto$findElement(using = 'css selector',value = "input~ input+ input")
boton_sexo$highlightElement()
boton_sexo$clickElement()
boton_sexo$goBack()
#####
boton_edad <- controlador_remoto$findElement(using = 'css selector',value = "form:nth-child(5) input")
boton_edad$highlightElement()
boton_edad$clickElement()
```

Answer (score 1):

Below a possible solution.

Active the web driver

```
library(RSelenium)
driver <- rsDriver(browser=c("firefox"), port = 4445L)
remote_driver <- driver[["client"]]
```

Send the url to firefox

```
remote_driver$navigate("https://listanominal.ine.mx/ESTADISTICAS/index.php")
```

Opens the list **estadisticas**

```
remote_driver$findElement(using = 'xpath', value = '/html/body/div[1]/ul/li[2]/a')$clickElement()
```

Click the **por sexo**

```
remote_driver$findElement(using = 'xpath', value = '/html/body/div[1]/ul/li[2]/ul/form[1]/input[3]')$clickElement()
```

Click the  **entidad de origen**

```
 remote_driver$findElement(using = 'xpath', value = '/html/body/div[1]/ul/li[2]/ul/form[2]/input[2]')$clickElement()
```

Click the **grupos de edad**

```
remote_driver$findElement(using = 'xpath', value = '/html/body/div[1]/ul/li[2]/ul/form[3]/input[2]')$clickElement()
```

I suggest you that when you find difficulty with the `css selector`, you could try the `xpath`

Comment: You are welcome!!! :D 
If the answer was helpful you might as well accept it.